# Zend3 Doctrine Entity passing parameters

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework3

```
+-----------------+    +------------------------------------+
|   item table    |    |          description table         |
+----+------+-----+    +----+---------+------+--------------+
| id | name | ... |    | id | item_id | lang |     text     |
+----+------+-----+    +----+---------+------+--------------+
|  1 | 1st  | ... |    |  1 |       1 |   en | english text |
+----+------+-----+    +----+---------+------+--------------+
|  2 | 2nd  | ... |    |  2 |       1 |   de | deutsch text |
+----+------+-----+    +----+---------+------+--------------+
                       |  3 |       2 |   en | english text |
                       +----+---------+------+--------------+

class Item {
   ...
   /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\Application\Entity\Desc", mappedBy="item")
    */
    protected $description;
   ...
}

class Desc {
   ...
   /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Application\Entity\Item", inversedBy="description")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="item_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    protected $item;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="text")
    protected $text;

    public function getDesc(/*passing lang*/)
    {
        //there returned array of values, not single result
        return $this->text;
    }
   ...
}
```

I have two table with OneToMany relatives. I set @ORM comment tag in entities and succesfully get descriptions array in item entity (EN and De lang). How I can to get only one lang description by passing lang argument to description entity without array iteration and excess SQL row in DB query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Item` Class, you can do something like this, which will return only the description with the specified language parameter:

```
/**
 *
 * @return \Application\Entity\Desc
 */
public function getDescByLanguage($language)
{
    $criteria = Criteria::create()
        ->where(Criteria::expr()->eq("lang", $language))
        ->setFirstResult(0)
        ->setMaxResults(1);

    $descByLanguage = $this->description->matching($criteria);

    return $descByLanguage[0];
}
```